# Scrapy: crawling webpages in sequence and yielding scraped data in a custom function

Tags: python, scrapy

I'd like to use Scrapy to crawl a marketplace website for items sold.
I want to do this one item at a time, because, e.g. if I make a call for item no 555566, and there's no such item, the webpage just says 'Incorrect item' and I can close the spider only after the response is passed. By then Scrapy will make calls for more pages and I don't want that.

Scrapy first crawls the starting item page in `start_requests` method, then makes a call to the api to get data on the sale of this particular item in the `parse` method, then extracts the data in the `parse_item` method. I want to yield this data in a separate function, because I need to call the `start_requests` method again with the next item number at the end of `parse_item` method.

And that's the part that I'm struggling with.

1. Calling `start_requests` again doesn't work.
2. If I comment out the `yield` command in the `yield_data` function, the item is printed in the console just fine. But with `yield` command uncommented, it seems that the program doesn't even enter the `yield_data` function. Why is that?

I'd appreciate any help with this.
Here's the code:

```
import scrapy
import json
from scrapy.exceptions import CloseSpider

class_itemsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
     name = 'items'

     id = 555555
     def start_requests(self):        
         url = 'https://market.com/item/' + str(self.id)
         index = self.id
         self.id += 1
         yield scrapy.Request(url, meta={'index':index})

     def parse(self, response):
         index = response.meta['index']
         if b'Incorrect' in response.body:
             raise CloseSpider('Incorrect item')
         url = 'https://market.com/api/item?ajax=1&itemid=' + str(index)
    
         request = scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_item, 
             headers={
                 'accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
                 'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'
             })
         yield request

     def parse_item(self, response):
         raw_data = response.body
         data = json.loads(raw_data)
         item = {
                 'Name':data['name'],
                 'Price':data['price'],
             }

         self.yield_data(item)
         # call start_requests again
         self.start_requests()

     def yield_data(self,_item):
         self.logger.info('Printing_item')
         print(item)
         self.logger.info('Yielding_item')
         yield item
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out. Maybe it will help someone.
I was thinking of `yield` as something that finishes execution of the code, but you can yield data and then yield a request with a callback to `parse` method.

```
import scrapy
import json
from scrapy.exceptions import CloseSpider

class_itemsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'items'
    id = 555555

    start_urls = ['https://market.com/item/' + str(id)]
    
    def parse(self, response):
        if b'Invalid' in response.body:
            raise CloseSpider('Invalid item')

        index = self.id
        self.id += 1
        
        url = 'https://market.com/api/item?ajax=1&itemid=' + str(index)
        
        request = scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_item, 
            headers={
                'accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
                'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}, 
                 meta={'index':index})
  
        yield request

    def parse_item(self, response):
        index = response.meta['index']
        raw_data = response.body
        data = json.loads(raw_data)
        yield {
            'Name':data['name'],
            'Price':data['price'],
             }

        url = 'https://market.com/item/' + str(self.id)
        yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse)
```